# GIT LFS with Artifactory's multi-push replication feature

Tags: git, artifactory, git-lfs

We are in the process of evaluating GIT  LFS and Artifactory for storing large binary files. The local (main) Artifactory server will have multi-push replication enabled so our satellite offices servers (oversees) can receive the large files. However, if the git-lfs pointer file contains a "local" lfs-url endpoint, it will (presumably?) download the large file from our local Artifactory server and NOT the remote server at our satellite offices (thereby downloading the large files over the network, which is not desirable).

My question is; -how will GIT LFS know which Artifactory server to retrieve the large file from when a user performs a fetch or clone?

Our hope is for the remote servers to receive the large files (via Artifactory replication), AND for those files to be downloaded from the server at the remote (oversees) sites, and NOT from our local Artifactory server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The git lfs pointer file does not include the lfs URL. It contains the object id and size, for example:

```
version https://git-lfs.github.com/spec/v1
oid sha256:ea824d6f0abeedf87be8951e4535c25d4d2955adfd435cfee956e72af6f258c9
size 4570923
```

When cloning the git project in your satellite sites, you can configure a lfs-url which points to the local Artifactory and lfs will pull the files from there.

Comment: Thanks @drob for your feedback and correction. I suspected some manual intervention may be needed to configure the correct lfs-urls for the satellite offices. I was hoping for some automated way to perform the lfs-url transformation perhaps within Artifactory configuration. I guess that was wishful thinking.. :) -thanks again.

Comment: Depending on how you provision the satellite office environment, you might be able to automate this. Another option is using a "geo DNS" mechanism which will point to the local Artifactory. This will allow to the same hostname in all sites.

Comment: Thanks again. I'll look into the automation methods, as this will be a requirement for this implementation. I'll upvote ASAP.